# SKStoreReviewController prompt limit after app upgrade

Tags: ios, storekit

I am trying to implement SKStoreReviewController for app review. I read that iOS automatically limits the display of the prompt to three occurrences per app within a 365-day period. 
Will app review prompt limit will get reset after app upgrade?

Below is the scenario

1. App v1.0 install
2. display app review prompts for every 10 launches so all the prompt
   limit of 3 is displayed
3. Within 365 days, the app upgraded to 2.0 so will app review prompt
   displayed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this limit is per application installation cycle. So you can ask for 3 times in 365 days, even if you published new update, your limit won't get reset until and unless user reinstall the app after uninstalling.